# submitting app to itunes connect no build shows

Tags: xcode, build, app-store, app-store-connect

I finally finished my app .
I did validation to my archive and clicked submit to appStore using xCode , after some minutes xCode showed me a success message , I went to my itunes connect and the plus button (above the build) is enabled , but when I click on it shows me nothing , and in prerelease I see nothing , I tried to upload it again , and xCode shows me a message which says that the app has been uploaded .
what's wrong !?

Comment: Have the same issue atm...

Comment: It takes 15-20 minutes for the build to show up in iTunes Connect. Check again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes 15-30 minutes for show-up in iTunes Connect.

Have patience !!

Comment: build version processing progress display but final build version not visible how to this solve this problem